# How to access union inside structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions

I have the following code:

```
/* sample.c */ 
    #include<stdio.h> 
    #include<malloc.h> 
    #include<stdlib.h> 
    #include"hermes.h" 
    #include<string.h> 

    int main (){
        struct hermes *h ;
        h = ( struct hermes *) malloc ( sizeof ( struct hermes *));

        strcpy ( h->api->search_response->result_code , "123" );
            printf("VALue : %s\n" , h->api->search_response->result_code );
        return 0; 
    }

/* hermes.h */ 
    struct hermes {

     union  {

          /* search response */
                    struct  {
                            int error_code;
                            char *result_code;
                            char *user_track_id;
                            struct bus_details bd;
                    }*search_response;

        }*api;
    };
```

I get a segmentation fault when I try to access the elements. Could anyone tell me what is the right way to access these elements?

Comment: You have a struct inside of a union inside of a struct. Perhaps it's my inexperience in C, but I have no idea what that structure might be useful for. What's the point here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this struct:

```
#define MAX 512 /* any number you want*/

struct hermes {
     union  {

          /* search response */
                    struct  {
                            int error_code;
                            char result_code[MAX];
                            char user_track_id[MAX];/* can use different sizes too*/
                            struct bus_details bd;
                    }search_response[MAX];/* can use different sizes too*/

        }*api;
    };
```

Or if you want to use your current struct, malloc the pointer element like:

```
 h->api = malloc((sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*MAX*2+sizeof(struct bus_details))*MAX)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `malloc()` line isn't correct:

```
h = ( struct hermes *) malloc ( sizeof ( struct hermes *));
```

should be:

```
h = ( struct hermes *) malloc ( sizeof ( struct hermes));
```

Remove the `*` in the `sizeof()`. Otherwise, you're only allocating enough for a pointer rather than the struct itself.

Also, the cast isn't necessary in C.

Comment: Or maybe `h = malloc(sizeof *h);`

Comment: You also need to initialize the pointers in the struct. As your code is right now, `h->api` is a dangling pointer. So it will seg-fault when you try to deference it.

Comment: Is the above malloc is not enough for all these inner unions and struct ? , need to allocate memory all the inner elements seperately ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The `malloc()` only allocates enough for the `struct` itself. It doesn't initialize any of the members itself. So you will need to go one step further and allocate memory for the pointers which you will use.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem of accessing the elements. That's about all that you are doing correctly.

Here are some of the things that are wrong. First, you aren't allocating enough space for a `hermes` struct, just enough for a pointer. Then, even if you `malloc( sizeof ( struct hermes ) );`, the one element (`api`) is an uninitialized pointer. You can't just follow uninitialized pointers down deep into the data structure, because they will be pointing to who knows where in memory. You first need to allocate something for `h->api` to point to. Then you need to allocate space for `h->api->search_response`. If you correct all that, then you are copying a string to ... who knows where? You should use `strdup`, not `strcpy` to create a new string, then you should assign the return value to `result_code`. Also, your union has only one element, so it's kind of pointless (unless there's more to it that you haven't posted).

**EDIT** Here's one way of initializing `h`:

```
h = malloc( sizeof( struct hermes ) );
h->api = malloc( sizeof( *h->api ) );
h->api->search_response = malloc( sizeof( h->api->search_response ) );
h->api->search_response->result_code = strdup( "123" );
```

Note that in a well-behaved program that cleans up after itself, each of these allocations will have to be freed individually as well, in reverse order of the calls to `malloc`. Since you immediately call `exit(0)`, no harm is done in this case if you don't.

Comment: can u explain how to allocate memory to h->api and h->api->search_response

Comment: @abubacker - I added to my answer